# Azure App Configuration Store - Setting label on keyvalues using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to add values to an Azure App Configuration Store using Bicep. I have an issue where I add a label to a keyValue.

This is my module:

```
@description('Configuration Store Name')
param configurationStoreName string

@description('key prefix')
param prefix string

@description('key name')
param keyName string

@description('value')
param value string

@description('content type')
param contentType string = 'string'

@description('Deployment Environment')
param deploymentEnvironment string = 'dev'

resource configurationStore 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores@2021-10-01-    preview' existing = {
name: configurationStoreName
}

resource configurationStoreValue     'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/keyValues@2021-10-01-preview' = {
  name: '${prefix}:${keyName}'
  parent: configurationStore
  properties: {
    contentType: contentType
    value: value
    tags: {
      environment: deploymentEnvironment
    }
  }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to add a label, which I want to do to enable filtering.

It can be done when creating KeyValues using the Azure Portal, therefore it should be possible using Bicep.

Am I missing something, or is this missing functionality from Bicep?

Comment: You mean you can't the tags being applied ?

Comment: The tags are being applied. But I want to add Labels, which are a different thing, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT April 2022**
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-resource-manager) has now been updated

> The `keyValues` resource's name is a combination of key and label. The key and label are joined by the `$` delimiter. The label is optional. In the above example, the `keyValues` resource with name `myKey` creates a key-value without a label.
>
> Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding, allows keys or labels to include characters that are not allowed in ARM template resource names. `%` is not an allowed character either, so `~` is used in its place. To correctly encode a name, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Apply URL encoding
> 2. Replace `~` with `~7E`
> 3. Replace `%` with `~`
>
> For example, to create a key-value pair with key name `AppName:DbEndpoint` and label name `Test`, the resource name should be `AppName~3ADbEndpoint$Test`.

I tried this approach and it works:

```bicep
@description('Configuration Store Name')
param configurationStoreName string

@description('key prefix')
param prefix string

@description('key name')
param keyName string

@description('value')
param value string

@description('label')
param label string

@description('content type')
param contentType string = 'string'

@description('Deployment Environment')
param deploymentEnvironment string = 'dev'

resource configurationStore 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores@2021-10-01-preview' existing = {
  name: configurationStoreName
}

var keyValueName = empty(label) ? '${prefix}:${keyName}' : '${prefix}:${keyName}$${label}'

resource configurationStoreValue 'Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/keyValues@2021-10-01-preview' = {
  name: keyValueName
  parent: configurationStore
  properties: {
    contentType: contentType
    value: value
    tags: {
      environment: deploymentEnvironment
    }
  }
}
```